# Can I use Apache FileNameUtils to get the Unix path from Url

Tags: url, file-upload, filepath, apache-commons-io

I am deploying my web application to unix server for the first time.We have fileUpload  functionality in our application. The file upload path is

```
 String url = "\\\\corp.test.sample.com\\corp\\Docs\\Upload\\test";
```

But when i use this on the Unix server I am getting null pointer exception.I found out on website I can [Apache FileNameUtills](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html)
to get the above path in Unix by using method `FileNameUtils.separatorsToSystem(url);` returns me the path which i can use in Unix environment. Is this best one or are there any other APIs which I can path which works on Unix?

Comment: So all you need to do is turn a string with potentially the "wrong" path separator into one you can use on your system?

Comment: @MattBall......I'm sorry i didn't get you.am I using wrong url(above path) in my windows and trying to get unix path out of it?is that what u mean?But this is perfectly working in windows.